# Co-registration of two DEM raster

Tags: dem, software-recommendations, elevation, coregistration

I have 2 different elevation files, a ALOS GDSM elevation set & a DSM extracted from Corona imagery. Since the Corona file has some inevitable offsets (mainly in z, non-systematic across the area covered), I wonder if there is a method or software available to co-register those 2 DEM files in xyz that doesn't involve python or R.

I know of these 2 examples, but Python is not my strong suite.
https://github.com/dshean/demcoreg
https://www.the-cryosphere.net/5/271/2011/tc-5-271-2011.html